# How to load DLL using Iron python?

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, dllimport

I wrote the simplest DLL using C# and copied it to the desktop.
Now I wanted to load the DLL in order to see that I can use the API but I get some errors:

the code I used: (edited after looking at some questions here)

```
import clr
import sys
sys.path.Add("C:\Desktop\DLLTest.dll")
clr.AddReference("C:\Desktop\DLLTest.dll")
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly DLLTest.dll
```

what is needed to be added to sys path? why?
thanks!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

User `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath` and double your backslashes. So:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('C:\\Desktop\\DLLTest.dll')
```

Comment: small improvement: import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'C:\Desktop\DLLTest.dll')